# Why Missing artifact?

Tags: maven, swagger, artifact

This is part of the pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

An it is creating some files in the local repository but not the jar

those are the files created for swagger-models

1. m2e-lastUpdated.properties

   swagger-models-1.0.1.jar.lastUpdated

   swagger-models-1.0.1.pom.lastUpdated

   swagger-models-1.0.1-sources.jar.lastUpdated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven dependencies in local REPO have .lastUpdated extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767311/maven-dependencies-in-local-repo-have-lastupdated-extension)

Comment: The problem is based that `swagger-models` in version [1.0.1 does not exist in Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22io.swagger%22%20AND%20a%3A%22swagger-models%22).

Comment: The two comments above explain your situation: the artifact does not exist in Maven Central, hence you end up with a `.lastUpdated` file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `swagger-models` version 1.x.  the io.swagger / swagger-models artifact was introduced in 1.5.0--you should be using 1.5.7