# Maven - dependency not downloading into local repository

Tags: java, dependencies, maven-3

I'm new to maven and have an issue downloading a dependency defined in pom.xml into my local respository.
All other dependencies defined in pom.xml are downloaded correctly. Also, other dependencies across multiple projects are also working fine.
I'm using maven 3.5.2 and aws sdk 1.11.86

The dependency causing problems is an aws redshift driver defined as -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
    <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.17.1017</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven Repository - `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/1.1.17.1017`

My local repo has the following -

```
com\amazon\redshift-jdbc4\1.1.17.1017
redshift-jdbc42-1.1.17.1017.jar.lastUpdated
redshift-jdbc42-1.1.17.1017.pom.lastUpdated
```

I've deleted the local .lastUpdated files, but that doesn't resolve.
Any ideas please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this solution [local REPO have .lastUpdated extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767311/maven-dependencies-in-local-repo-have-lastupdated-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that the jar redshift-jdbc42 is unavailable is maven central. However, it is available in mule soft public repo.

What you need is to add a repository section in your pom.xml, something like this.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-repo</id>
          <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.